# Creating a Request Params for batchWriteItem(params,function(){}) in javaScript

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have been trying to create params for batchWriteItem(), when I create them like this it perfactly works.

```
var params = {
RequestItems: {
    'tableNameXYZ' :  [ //hardcoded
   {
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz
        },...
       }
      },
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz1
        },...
       }
      }
  }
 ]
};
```

But I am unable to work on it when I have table name in a variable:

```
var tableName = 'tableNameXYZ';
var params = {
RequestItems: {
    tableName :  [ 
   {
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz
        },...
       }
      },
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz1
        },...
       }
      }
  }
 ]
};
```

Obviously this wouldn't have worked since I played rough with JSON object here.
Then I tried this:

```
var params = {};
params.RequestItems[tableName] = [
   {
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz
        },...
       }
      },
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": xyz1
        },...
       }
      }
  }
 ];
```

Now its throwing me an error like:

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'tableNameXYZ' of undefined
at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:181:32)
```

Can someone Pointout my mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this error because:

```
var params = {};
```

Creates an empty object (called `params`) with no properties, but:

```
params.RequestItems[tableName] = [ // ...rest of code
```

Tries to assign `params.RequestItems.the-value-of-tableName`.

But `params` has no property called `RequestItems` and so, `params.RequestItems` is undefined. And it is a `TypeError` to try and set the value of   a property (in this case `the-value-of-tableName`) on `undefined`.

To fix this, use:

```
var params = {};
params.RequestItems = {}; // assign RequestItems an empty object.
params.RequestItems[tableName] = [ // ...rest of code.
```